# Remove first and last character if has specific character in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Please help me to remove the first and last character if it has specific character (`#`) in the string otherwise do not remove?

Input 1:  `#Test#SQL#`

Desired Output : `Test#SQL`

Input 2: `Test#SQL`

Desired Output : `Test#SQL`

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an another perspective by using a `CASE` expression and a combination of `LEFT` and `RIGHT` string functions.

**Query**

```
select case when left(@str, 1) = '#' and right(@str, 1) = '#'
then left((right(@str, len(@str) - 1)), len((right(@str, len(@str) - 1))) - 1)
when left(@str, 1) = '#' and right(@str, 1) <> '#'
then right(@str, len(@str) - 1)
when left(@str, 1) <> '#' and right(@str, 1) = '#'
then left(@str, len(@str) - 1)
else @str end as str;
```

**[Find a demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/668248/remove-first-and-last-character-if-has-specific-character-in-sql-server)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RIGHT` and `LEFT` like this:

```
Update myTable set myField = RIGHT(myField,LEN(myField)-1) WHERE myField LIKE '#%';
Update myTable set myField = LEFT(myField,LEN(myField)-1) WHERE myField LIKE '%#';
```

This will ensure that even if the value starts **or** ends with the `#` symbol, it will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most efficient way, but you could put it in a function easily enough:

Essentially, you test the first character in the string and remove it if it's the # sign.  Then you do the same with the last character.

```
DECLARE @A VARCHAR(25)
SET @A = '#Test#SQL#'

SET @A = CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING(@A, 1, 1) = '#'
        THEN SUBSTRING(@A, 2, LEN(@A))
        ELSE @A
    END

SET @A = CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING(@A, LEN(@A) , 1) = '#'
        THEN SUBSTRING(@A, 1, LEN(@A) - 1)
        ELSE @A
    END

SELECT @A
```